# Add a newline with re.findall

Tags: python, regex

I got a giant list with strings that I want to extract using regex. Everything works but all the extracted strings are in one line, I want them all to have their own line

My code

```
import re

with open("alldorks.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as dork_list:
    for text in dork_list:
        sub1 = "[<h6><b>Dork:</b> "
        sub2 = "</h6>,"
        sample = re.sub(re.findall(r"</b>(.+?)</h6>", text), sample + "\n")
        print(sample)
```

a sample of the txt

```
[<h6><b>Dork:</b> intext:"© JARDCS 2020 All right reserved"</h6>
```

The `re.findall` works as intended, but adding a newline with `re.sub` does not work.

Comment: Either your code is incomplete, or you are referencing `sample` before it is declared.

Comment: this is my entire code

Comment: After `with open("alldorks.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as dork_list:` just use `print( "\n".join(re.findall(r'</b>(.+?)</h6>', dork_list.read())) )`

Comment: Regular expressions are a poor fit for html.  May I recommend https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/ ?

Comment: Did my solution help?